# Android Basic Authentication 2.2+

Tags: android

HI,

I am struggeling with Basic HTTP Authentication like I have seen many others..

```
public String getJSONObject()
    {
        try
        {
        String strURL = "deleted_manually_here";

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(
                (username+":"+password).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(strURL);

        post.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);



        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody=client.execute(post, responseHandler);
        JSONObject response=new JSONObject(responseBody);

        Log.d(TAG,"SUCCESS!");

        return "B";

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION in updateStatus()", t);
            return "N";
        }
    }
```

Where username & password is a private final String.

But in my adb logcat I get:

E/GetHttpQuotes(  392): EXCEPTION in updateStatus() << my log text"
E/GetHttpQuotes(  392): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied << so something is wrong..

I tried so many code I found but nothing worked...

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET

Comment: omg.. how can you know.. at least I seem to got permission now ending up with:

/GetHttpQuotes(  347): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request

Which seems to have a mistake anywhere else.

I am using Emulator and was assuming I got network connection because I was also able to surf on the browser.

Comment: You'd normally get a 401 Authorization failed if your basic auth wasn't working, so I think Peter is correct.

Comment: Yes, Peter is correct and I got it working now. Seems to be hanging all up to the Permission ;) Thx guys, can be so easy:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is pretty simple!

The Internet Permission in the Android Manifest was missing which is pretty fundamental to check in problems like these at first.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET