# How to create basic access authentication on Android?

Tags: android

I have implemented basic authorization in my android application in similar way as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850667/android-basic-authentication-2-2) but I continue get an error as html page:

```
HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid
```

I check my url at many times but don't find any problem with it. So my question is could this error occurs with reason is not related with form of my url?

Comment: what is your url ?...........

Comment: Simple url as this: http://server.com/category/page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please confirm the URL " server.com/category/page" is right as when uses HTTP

[image]

but with out http it's working

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is true, for this url a ping doesn't work. Could you please suggest how I can work with this? Or Is it a issue of server?

Comment: basically  http request not working for this url see 2nd image